Is there any way to update caption of excel's Slicers using c# code for spire.xls
Is there any way to update caption of excelsheet's Slicers using c# code for spire.xls
I have tried some part of code googled through internet but it was only for PivotTables and not for the Slicers. I need help for the mentioned concern about Slicers of the excelsheet.

I haven't got a chance to try it myself, but I think you can use this: https://github.com/EPPlusSoftware/EPPlus.Samples.CSharp/blob/master/07-Tables%20pivot%20tables%20and%20slicers/03-Slicers/SlicerSample.cs
